# Disable linkbuttons in ASP.NET 4.0 when other CSS Classes are being used

Tags: asp.net, css, linkbutton

I'll try to explain my problem.

I have this linkbutton with a CssClass:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="test"
    Text="delete"
    CssClass="button blue"
    OnClick="DeleteMessage_Click"
    runat="server" />
```

When I disable this linkbutton the class is rendered like this:

```
<a id="test" class="aspNetDisabled button blue">delete</a>
```

`aspNetDisabled` is the first class. Now I want to make the button look grey but after the `aspNetDisabled` style is the `button` style and the `blue` style so the button is never going to be grey.

Is it possible to render `aspNetDisabled` last, after the `button` style and the `blue` style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
a.button
{
   color: gray !important;
}
```

Just out of curiosity, what is the blue class for, if you want to make the button gray?

Comment: Normal the button is blue, but when I disable the button I want the button to be gray.

Comment: Thanks.. the !important tag works.. I added !important to the aspNetDisabled style and now the buttons are gray when they are disabled.